# Hide google form field

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

Please tell me about the form. Is there a way to hide specific question items when answering a survey? We are considering a method to pre-enter parameters for each respondent in the hidden items.

Comment: I couldn't image about `pre-enter parameters for each respondent in the hidden items`. Can I ask you about the detail information of it?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't hidden fields on Forms, but there is a workaround. You can use different sections to store your prefilled fields in a second [section](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737) (refer to *Add a section*) just before user upload. You can't skip that section, otherwise the prefilled data will be ignored in the results page. You should inform the user not to modify those questions to prevent accidental modifications (programming a [response validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864) is a good idea too).

As an alternative, you could fill a feature request at [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) so Google engineers can think about adding support to hidden fields.

Do not hesitate to ask for further clarification if you still have doubts.

Comment: Hi there @tomoharuhishikawa! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.